# Highcharts multi line graphs display when requested

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a4UQf/

Code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
});
```

Here I want to implement in php mysql. Some suggestions would be grateful.

Before that the lines showing there, there must be a check then the graph should show, for example if i click on tokyo checkbox then tokyo line graph should show and so on, this should be used in an array, how to do that please help.

Comment: No actually I am same person bro check my name bro, look at that example this is what i need.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19129422/1920232 Stop posting the same question under different names